# Replacing character by carrage return in mail

Tags: vba, outlook

I get an automatically generated email in outlook from a system whose formatting cannot be controlled.  I want to replace every comma in the email with a carriage return which would result in an easy to read and process output.   I was thinking of doing this via a VB script

I can do this in Word OK via VB using the script below but don't know the equivalent in outlook

```
Sub Macro2()
'
' Macro2 Macro
'
'
    Selection.Find.ClearFormatting
    Selection.Find.Replacement.ClearFormatting
    With Selection.Find
        .Text = ","
        .Replacement.Text = "^l"
        .Forward = True
        .Wrap = wdFindContinue
        .Format = False
        .MatchCase = False
        .MatchWholeWord = False
        .MatchWildcards = False
        .MatchSoundsLike = False
        .MatchAllWordForms = False
    End With
    Selection.Find.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
End Sub
```

what I want would convert a mail:

```
Request ID: 527
Results: [06-641-20_XABY_C-terminally designated_region A, 46-643-00_AASC_C-terminally designated_region C, 06-642-60_TTTS_C-terminally designated_region S]
```

to:

```
Request ID: 527
Results: [06-641-20_XABY_C-terminally designated_region A<br>
 46-643-00_AASC_C-terminally designated_region C<br>
 06-642-60_TTTS_C-terminally designated_region S]
```

So each result lines up - very often there are dozens of results!

Answer (score 0):

What you want is a simple replace, like this:

```
Option Explicit

Sub test()
    Dim textFromEmail As String
    textFromEmail = "Request ID: 527" & vbNewLine & _
                    "Results: [06-641-20_XABY_C-terminally designated_region A, 46-643-00_AASC_C-terminally designated_region C, 06-642-60_TTTS_C-terminally designated_region S] "
    Debug.Print Replace(textFromEmail, ",", vbNewLine)
End Sub
```

Comment: You might also want to align the first one   Replace(textFromEmail, "[", "[" & vbNewLine)

Comment: Thanks Peter - unless I have misunderstood, in your code the text being changed 'textfromemail' is defined in the code - how do I just make the macro look at all the text in the email?

Comment: Your code will access the [`Mailitem`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.mailitem), then you can get the text from the `MailItem.Body` property. You can probably find plenty of examples online to show how to build your code to do that. Then apply the `Replace` statement from my answer.

Comment: Thanks All - I have a successful macro now